# Cant find types in stripe.NET-payments basic example (Xamarin)

Tags: mobile, xamarin.forms, stripe-payments, credit-card

Im trying to make a Xamarin app from [this guide](https://xamarinhelp.com/stripe-in-xamarin/) containing a credit card payment but it cant find (Almost) any of the types. Is this guide pure fantasy or (more likely) am I mistunderstanding something? I have downloaded the Stripe.Net nuget-package and using all Stripe namespaces I can find. The Shortcut "Ctrl + ." does not help. What Im I missing

(Never ming the PUBLISHABLE_KEY, thats my own constant,I cut the definiton out from the example)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide you're following is using an older version of the stripe-dotnet library, and in the [latest releases](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/v20_migration_guide.md) many types were renamed, e.g. StripeTokenCreateOptions is now TokenCreateOptions.